# Special characters to the end of sentence

Tags: python, character

For a random string such as:

`H!i I am f.rom G3?ermany`

how can I move all the special characters to the end of the word, for instance:

`Hi! I am from. Germany3?`

Comment: Define _special characters_. And show us what you've done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one :

```
s = "H!i I am f.rom G3?ermany"
l = []
for i in s.split():
    k = [j for j in i if j.isalpha()]
    for m in i:
        if not m.isalpha():
           k.append(m)
    l.append(''.join(k))
print(' '.join(l))
```

It will o/p like :

```
"Hi! I am from. Germany3?
```

In **python 2x** you can do it in single line like :

```
k = ' '.join([filter(str.isalpha,i)+''.join([j for j in i if not j.isalpha()]) for i in s.split()])
```

Comment: This code is an abomination...

Answer (score 1):

I'm defining special character as anything thats not a-z, A-Z or spaces:

You can split the string into words, use regex to find the special characters in each word, remove them, add them back to the end of the word, then join the words together to create your new string:

```
import re

string = "H!i I am f.rom G3?ermany"

words = string.split(' ')

pattern = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z\s]')

new = ' '.join([re.sub(pattern, '', w) + ''.join(pattern.findall(w)) for w in words])
```

That will turn `H!i I am f.rom G3?ermany` into `Hi! I am from. Germany3?`